# jest mocking implementation once, tests won't run typescript errors

Tags: typescript, jestjs

So I have a function, that takes three arguments, if I try and spyOn it and use mockImplementationOnce I get all sorts of typescript errors, how to use this function and not have the errors?

This runs fine, with just one arguments, the callback.

```
const people = {
  person: person,
};

function person(cb: any) {
  const person = {
    age: 'frank',
    name: 'bob',
  };
  return cb(person);
}

const clientSpy = jest.spyOn(people, 'person');
clientSpy.mockImplementationOnce(cb => cb('bob'));
```

But if I provide the person function with some arguments I get all sorts of errors.

```
const people = {
  person: person,
};

function person(name: string, age: string, cb: any) {
  const person = {
    age,
    name,
  };
  return cb(person);

const clientSpy = jest.spyOn(people, 'person');
clientSpy.mockImplementationOnce(("james", "age", cb) => cb('bob'));
```

Screenshot of the errors, what should I be doing, to get this to work.

[image: Error messages]

Comment: It looks like you've misplaced the strings. Instead of passing the extra arguments, you've put them in the parameter definition. Did you mean `clientSpy.mockImplementationOnce((cb) => cb('bob', 'james', 'age'));` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mockImplementationOnce` functions's first parameter is a callback that is a mock implementation of what would actually get invoked (a.k.a another function). The reason why TypeScript is complaining here is because you have provided string literals in the place of the mock function parameters - `"james", "age"` which is the equivalent of doing:

`function bob("james", "age", cb) => {}`

Which is not valid.

What you need to do instead is to repeat the parameters you have in the actual function, and then invoke the callback with mock values as follows:

```
clientSpy.mockImplementationOnce((name: string, age: string, cb: any) => cb('bob'));
```